# Pass a string parameter in an onclick function

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to pass a parameter (i.e. a string) to an Onclick function.

For the moment, I do this:

```
'<input type="button" onClick="gotoNode(' + result.name + ')" />'
```

with result.name for example equal to string "Add".

When I click on this button, I have an error that says that *"Add is not defined"*. Since this function call works perfectly with a numeric parameter, I assume that it has something to do with the symbols "" in the string.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: It might be better in this case to simply not use inline event handlers.

Comment: Your problem is due to the variable not being escaped properly. Check [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9643494/295264)

Answer (score 448, accepted):

It looks like you're building DOM elements from strings. You just need to add some quotes around result.name:

```
'<input type="button" onClick="gotoNode(\'' + result.name + '\')" />'
```

You should really be doing this with proper DOM methods though.

```
var inputElement = document.createElement('input');
inputElement.type = "button"
inputElement.addEventListener('click', function(){
    gotoNode(result.name);
});

​document.body.appendChild(inputElement);​
```

Just be aware that if this is a loop or something, `result` will change before the event fires and you'd need to create an additional scope bubble to shadow the changing variable.

Comment: Hi @david..I have one doubt...I want to pass multiple argument in that onclick..how it possible? can you make useful for me..?

Comment: @david,thanks it solved my string parameter issue but now i have to pass (string, boolean). what to do for that?

Comment: @david : can you tell little bit why do we need to add quote around that

Comment: @hitesh if you don't add quotes, the string will be perceived as a variable.

Comment: @david What do you mean by scope bubble to shadow?

Comment: @david How do I create a scope bubble?

Comment: @JohnK The correct term is a 'closure' which might help your googling. Essentially you wrap it in another function and immediately call the function with the variable you wish to shadow.  These days though you can just use `let` or `const` instead of `var`.

Comment: addEventListener() not added in my case

Comment: Same thing but easier to read:
\`<input type="button" onClick="gotoNode('${result.name}')" />\`

Answer (score 58):

A couple of concerns for me with respect to using string escape in onClick and as the number of arguments grow, it will become cumbersome to maintain.

The following approach will have a one hop - On click - take the control to a handler method and handler method, based on the event object, can deduct the click event and corresponding object.

It also provides a cleaner way to add more arguments and have more flexibility.

```
<button type="button"
        className="btn btn-default"
        onClick="invoke"
        name='gotoNode'
        data-arg1='1234'>GotoNode</button>
```

In the JavaScript layer:

```
  invoke = (event) => {
    let nameOfFunction = this[event.target.name];
    let arg1 = event.target.getAttribute('data-arg1');
    // We can add more arguments as needed...
    window[nameOfFunction](arg1)
    // Hope the function is in the window.
    // Else the respective object need to be used
    })
  }
```

The advantage here is that we can have as many arguments (in above example, data-arg1, data-arg2, etc.) as needed.

Comment: I'm surprised this isn't getting more upvotes as it is the cleaner method of passing arguments to an event handler.

Comment: This does not work, `invoke` is not called when you click on the button

Comment: Great solution! If you need to pass Arrays or Objects just use `JSON.stringify(obj)` in the HTML and `JSON.parse(event.target.getAttribute('data-arg'))` in the JavaScript-layer

Comment: @SairamKrish In my case, if i click the button i have set to display id,  screenshot : https://snag.gy/7bzEWN.jpg  code : https://www.pastiebin.com/5d35674e2fc31

Comment: This may work, but it is an abstruse, atypical implementation that would be hard to follow for another developer that needed to maintain this.

Answer (score 31):

I suggest not even using HTML `onclick` handlers, and use something more common such as `document.getElementById`.

HTML:

```
<input type="button" id="nodeGoto" />
```

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("nodeGoto").addEventListener("click", function() {
    gotoNode(result.name);
}, false);
```

Comment: `onclick` is not a function, it's a property you have to assign a function to: `....onclick = function() {...};`

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks for that, my head's still in jQuery mode.

Comment: You're assuming there will be just one of these inputs.

Comment: Well the OP's question implies that there will only be one input.

Comment: I think this option doesn't work for me, because I generate multiple buttons as a result of a search-operation. I could solve this by using a counter to add to the id's but I want to keep it simple and keep it inline

Comment: @kevinji In my case, if i click the button i have set to display id,  screenshot : https://snag.gy/7bzEWN.jpg  code : https://www.pastiebin.com/5d35674e2fc31

Answer (score 27):

This is a nice and neat way to send a value or object.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <h1  onclick="test('wow',this)">Click on this text!</h1>
        <script>
            var test = function(value,object) {
                object.innerHTML= value;
            };
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 23):

I am guessing, you are creating a button using JavaScript itself. So, the **error** in your code is that, it will render in this form

```
<input type="button" onClick="gotoNode(add)" />'
```

At this current state, `add` will be considered as an identifier like variables or function calls. You should escape the value like this

```
'<input type="button" onClick="gotoNode(\'' + result.name + '\')" />'
```

Answer (score 13):

Try this...

HTML:

```
<button id="a1" type="button" onclick="return a1_onclick('a1')">a1</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function a1_onclick(id) {
        document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor = "#F00";
    }
</script>
```

Note: **be sure of sending arguments between ' ' signs like ('a1') in HTML code**

Comment: thanks!! been looking for this prob for couple hourss

Comment: Does anyone help?  In my case, if i click the button i have set to display id,  screenshot : https://snag.gy/7bzEWN.jpg  code : https://www.pastiebin.com/5d35674e2fc31

Answer (score 13):

If your button is generated dynamically:

You can pass string parameters to JavaScript functions like the below code:

I passed three parameters where the third one is a string parameter.

```
var btn ="<input type='button' onclick='RoomIsReadyFunc("+ID+","+RefId+",\""+YourString+"\");'  value='Room is Ready' />";

// Your JavaScript function

function RoomIsReadyFunc(ID, RefId, YourString)
{
  alert(ID);
  alert(RefId);
  alert(YourString);
}
```

Comment: Nice, Clean and simple. Thanks

Answer (score 10):

Also you can use the grave accent symbol ( ` ) in a string

Try:

```
`<input type="button" onClick="gotoNode('${result.name}')" />`
```

For more information, visit [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) and [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28088965/1772385).

By Chrome, Edge, Firefox (Gecko), [Opera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opera_%28web_browser%29), [Safari](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_%28web_browser%29) support, but it does not support Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 7):

If the requirement is to reference the global object (JavaScript) in your HTML code, you can try this. [Don't use any quotes (' or ") around the variable]

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gaJTb/)** reference.

JavaScript:

```
var result = {name: 'hello'};
function gotoNode(name) {
    alert(name);
}
```

HTML:

```
<input value="Hello" type="button" onClick="gotoNode(result.name)" />​
```

Comment: I get an error when I try this solution: the part "+ result.name +" is used as string in this case

Comment: what is "result" object? Is it a global variable declared in JS? like ... var result = {name: 'javascript'};

Comment: result contains a record from the jowl library: it's a json-structure with attributes name, type, ...

Comment: Jaspack, I have updated the answer. Does it work for you now?

Comment: Thank you for the example, but that doesn't work in my case: the result variable isn't global, but is a variable within a procedure. So when I call the function with result.name, result isn't known

Answer (score 5):

Multiple parameters:

```
bounds.extend(marker.position);
bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infowindow,
    '<b>' + response[i].driver_name + '</b><br>' +
    '<b>' + moment(response[i].updated_at).fromNow() + '</b>
     <button onclick="myFunction(\'' + response[i].id + '\',\'' + driversList + '\')">Click me</button>'
);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a reference or string value. Just put the function inside the double commas "" as per the below snapshot:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a jQuery solution that I'm using.

#### jQuery

```
$("#slideshow button").click(function(){
    var val = $(this).val();
    console.log(val);
});
```

#### HTML

```
<div id="slideshow">
    <img src="image1.jpg">
    <button class="left" value="back">&#10094;</button>
    <button class="right" value="next">&#10095;</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If to use for generation of a set of buttons with different parameters of handlers.

*[JavaScript Closures](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_closures.asp)*

```
let some_button = document.createElement( "button" );
some_button.type = "button";

some_button.onclick = doWithParam( some_param );

function doWithParam( param ){
    return function(){
        alert( param ); // <-- Your code here
    }
}
```

If we do:

```
some_button.onclick = foo( some_param );
function foo( param ){
    alert( param );
}
```

then function *foo* starts after every updating page.

If we do:

```
for( let i = 0; i < 10; ++i ){
    var inputElement = document.createElement('input');
    inputElement.type = "button"
    inputElement.addEventListener('click', function(){
        gotoNode(result.name);
    });

 ​   document.body.appendChild(inputElement);​
}
```

then for all buttons created in the loop, the last value of the parameter is "result.name".

Answer (score 1):

If you need to pass a variable along with the 'this' keyword, the below code works:

```
var status = 'Active';
var anchorHTML = '<a href ="#" onClick = "DisplayActiveStatus(this,\'' + status + '\')">' + data+ '</a>';
```

Comment: var status = 'Active';
var anchorHTML = '<a href ="#" onClick = "DisplayActiveStatus(this,\'' + status + '\')">' + data+ '</a>';

Answer (score 1):

```
<!----  script ---->
<script>
function myFunction(x) {
  document.getElementById("demo").style.backgroundColor = x; 
}
</script>

<!---- source ---->
<p id="demo" style="width:20px;height:20px;border:1px solid #ccc"></p>

<!----  buttons & function call ----> 
<a  onClick="myFunction('red')" />RED</a> 
<a  onClick="myFunction('blue')" />BLUE</a> 
<a  onClick="myFunction('black')" />BLACK</a>
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

This is work for me:

```
$(element).attr("onClick", 'functionName(' + "\"" + Object.attribute + "\"" + ')');
```

Just add \ slash in ()

※Multiple parameters example

```
"functionName(" + "'" + parameter1 + "','" + parameter2 + "','" + parameter3 + "','" + parameter4 + "','" + parameter5 + "','" + parameter6 + "')"
```

Answer (score 0):

For passing multiple parameters you can cast the string by concatenating it with the ASCII value. Like, for single quotes we can use `&#39;`:

```
var str = "&#39;" + str + "&#39;";
```

The same parameter you can pass to the `onclick()` event. In most of the cases it works with every browser.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<style type="text/css">
    #userprofile{
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 15px 25px;
        font-size: 24px;
        cursor: pointer;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        outline: none;
        color: #FFF;
        background-color: #4CAF50; // #C32836
        border: none;
        border-radius: 15px;
        box-shadow: 0 9px #999;
        width: 200px;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
    }
    #userprofile:hover {
        background-color: #3E8E41
    }

    #userprofile:active {
        background-color: #3E8E41;
        box-shadow: 0 5px #666;
        transform: translateY(4px);
    }

    #array {
        border-radius: 15px 50px;
        background: #4A21AD;
        padding: 20px;
        width: 200px;
        height: 900px;
        overflow-y: auto;
    }
</style>
```

```javascript
if (data[i].socketid != "") {
    $("#array").append("<button type='button' id='userprofile' class='green_button' name=" + data[i]._id + " onClick='chatopen(name)'>" + data[i].username + "</button></br>");
}
else {
    console.log('null socketid  >>', $("#userprofile").css('background-color'));
    //$("#userprofile").css('background-color', '#C32836 ! important');

    $("#array").append("<button type='button' id='userprofile' class='red_button' name=" + data[i]._id + " onClick='chatopen(name)'>" + data[i].username+"</button></br>");
    $(".red_button").css('background-color','#C32836');
}
```

Comment: Please explain your code, this answer by itself is not useful

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [ASP.NET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET) you can use JavaScript:

#### HTML

```
<input type='button' value='test' onclick='javascript: EditSelectedOptionName(x,y)' />"
```

#### JavaScript

```
function EditSelectedOptionName(id, name) {
    console.log(id);
    console.log(name);
}
```

Comment: Not [ASP Classic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Server_Pages), I presume?

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding buttons or link dynamically and facing the issue then this may be help. I solved it by this way:

```
var link= $(contentData1[i]).find("td:first font b a").attr("href",'javascript:onClick=openWin(\'' + tdText + '\')');
```

I am new to HTML, jQuery and JavaScript. So maybe my code will not be optimized or syntax, but it was working for me.

Answer (score 0):

In [Razor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_ASP.NET_Razor_view_engine), you can pass parameters dynamically:

```
<a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='showtotextbox(@Model.UnitNameVMs[i].UnitNameID, "@Model.UnitNameVMs[i].FarName","@Model.UnitNameVMs[i].EngName","@Model.UnitNameVMs[i].Symbol" );'>@Model.UnitNameVMs[i].UnitNameID</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
'<input id="test" type="button" value="' + result.name + '" />'

$(document).on('click', "#test", function () {
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

It worked for me.

Comment: What does "`..`" (two) mean?

Answer (score 0):

```
let task = {....}

<button onclick="myFunction('${task}')">Continue task</button></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not escaping double quotes is the cause of OP's problem. A readable approach to escape double quotes is using backticks ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)). Here is a sample solution:

`` my_btn.setAttribute('onclick', `my_func("${onclick_var1}", "${onclick_var2}")`); ``

Answer (score 0):

```
<button style="background-color: gray;color:white;" onclick="displayAlert('the message')">alert</button>
<script>
    function displayAlert(msg){
        alert(msg);
    }

</script>
```

Comment: When answering you should include a description of your code so that others can understand how it addresses the question as asked.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this code in your button onclick method:

```js
<button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="cancelEmployee(\''+cancelButtonID+'\')" > Cancel </button>
```

Answer (score -1):

The following works for me very well,

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>HTML Form</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input type="button" value="ON" onclick="msg('ON')">
        <input type="button" value="OFF" onclick="msg('OFF')">
    </form>
    <script>
        function msg(x){
            alert(x);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: OP is not asking about a constant value. This does not answer the question.