# Pass multiple values with onClick in HTML link

Tags: javascript, html

Hi Im trying to pass multiple values with the HTML onclick function. Im using Javascript to create the Table

```
var user = element.UserName;
var valuationId = element.ValuationId;
$('#ValuationAssignedTable').append('<tr> <td><a href=# onclick="return ReAssign(\'' + valuationId + ',' + user + '\')">Re-Assign</a> </td>  </tr>');
```

But in my Javascript function the userName is undefined and the valuationId is a string with the valuationId and the UserName combined

```
function ReAssign(valautionId, userName) {
    valautionId;
    userName;

}
```

Comment: ’<a href=# onclick="return ReAssign(valuationId, user)">Re-Assign</a>’

Comment: How are you generating the `<a>` tag?  It looks like you might be trying to do it via server-side code.  Otherwise, where are `valuationId` and `user` coming from?

Comment: You're passing the two variables within a single string... do as @ppeterka's answer states

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass a string parameter in an onclick function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9643311/pass-a-string-parameter-in-an-onclick-function)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

If `valuationId` and `user` are JavaScript variables, and the source code is plain static HTML, not generated by any means, you should try:

```
<a href=# onclick="return ReAssign(valuationId,user)">Re-Assign</a>
```

If they are generated from PHP, and they contain string values, use the escaped quoting around **each** variables like this:

```
<?php
    echo '<a href=# onclick="return ReAssign(\'' + $valuationId + '\',\'' + $user + '\')">Re-Assign</a>';
?>
```

The logic is similar to the updated code in the question, which generates code using JavaScript (maybe using jQuery?): don't forget to apply the escaped quotes to **each** variable:

```
var user = element.UserName;
var valuationId = element.ValuationId;
$('#ValuationAssignedTable').append('<tr> <td><a href=# onclick="return ReAssign(\'' + valuationId + '\',\'' + user + '\')">Re-Assign</a> </td>  </tr>');
```

**The moral of the story is**

```
'someString(\''+'otherString'+','+'yetAnotherString'+'\')'
```

Will get evaluated as:

```
someString('otherString,yetAnotherString');
```

Whereas you would need:

```
someString('otherString','yetAnotherString');
```

Comment: @ppeterkar I tried your code but I get this error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,

Comment: @JohandeKlerk fixed it, there were two backslashes in wrong position - manually escaping strings is something I don't like to deal with, because I frequently screw up which quote to escape and which not to... Not to mention if I have to double-escape, like when using in regexes...

Comment: This code is incorrect echo '<a href=# onclick="return ReAssign(\'' + $valuationId + \'','\\ + $user + '\')">Re-Assign</a>'; It should be like:echo '<a href=# onclick="return ReAssign(\'' + $valuationId + '\',\'' + $user + '\')">Re-Assign</a>';

Answer (score 12):

### **Solution: Pass multiple arguments with onclick for html generated in JS**

> For html generated in JS , do as below (we are using single quote as
>   string wrapper).
>   Each argument has to wrapped in a single quote else
>   all of yours argument will be considered as a single argument like
>   functionName('a,b') , now its a single argument with value a,b.
>
> We have to use string escape character backslash() to close first argument
>   with single quote, give a separator comma in between and then start next argument with a
>   single quote. (This is the magic code to use `'\',\''`)

### ***Example:***

```
$('#ValuationAssignedTable').append('<tr> <td><a href=# onclick="return ReAssign(\'' + valuationId  +'\',\'' + user + '\')">Re-Assign</a> </td>  </tr>');
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 $Name= "'".$row['Name']."'";
  $Val1= "'".$row['Val1']."'";
  $Year= "'".$row['Year']."'";
  $Month="'".$row['Month']."'";

 echo '<button type="button"   onclick="fun('.$Id.','.$Val1.','.$Year.','.$Month.','.$Id.');"  >submit</button>';
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. A couple of words of explanation will help the OP understand better.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help. A proper explanation [would greatly improve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made

Answer (score 3):

enclose each argument with backticks( ` )

example:

```
<button onclick="updateById(`id`, `name`)">update</button>

function updateById(id, name) {
   alert(id + name );
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try this

```
for static values--onclick="return ReAssign('valuationId','user')"
for dynamic values--onclick="return ReAssign(valuationId,user)"
```

Comment: This just made the trick! Surrounding each variable with single quotes. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That is because you pass string to the function. Just remove quotes and pass real values:

```
<a href=# onclick="return ReAssign(valuationId, user)">Re-Assign</a>
```

Guess the ReAssign function should return `true` or `false`.

Answer (score 0):

A few things here...

If you want to call a function when the onclick event happens, you'll just want the function name plus the parameters.

Then if your parameters are a variable (which they look like they are), then you won't want quotes around them. Not only that, but if these are global variables, you'll want to add in "window." before that, because that's the object that holds all global variables.

Lastly, if these parameters aren't variables, you'll want to exclude the slashes to escape those characters. Since the value of onclick is wrapped by double quotes, single quotes won't be an issue. So your answer will look like this...

```
<a href=# onclick="ReAssign('valuationId', window.user)">Re-Assign</a>
```

There are a few extra things to note here, if you want more than a quick solution.

You looked like you were trying to use the + operator to combine strings in HTML. HTML is a scripting language, so when you're writing it, the whole thing is just a string itself. You can just skip these from now on, because it's not code your browser will be running (just a whole bunch of stuff, and anything that already exists is what has special meaning by the browser).

Next, you're using an anchor tag/link that doesn't actually take the user to another website, just runs some code. I'd use something else other than an anchor tag, with the appropriate CSS to format it to look the way you want. It really depends on the setting, but in many cases, a span tag will do. Give it a class (like class="runjs") and have a rule of CSS for that. To get it to imitate a link's behavior, use this:

```
.runjs {
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: blue;
}
```

This lets you leave out the href attribute which you weren't using anyways.

Last, you probably want to use JavaScript to set the value of this link's onclick attribute instead of hand writing it. It keeps your page cleaner by keeping the code of your page separate from what the structure of your page. In your class, you could change all these links like this...

```
var links = document.getElementsByClassName('runjs');
for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++)
    links[i].onclick = function() { ReAssign('valuationId', window.user); };
```

While this won't work in some older browsers (because of the getElementsByClassName method), it's just three lines and does exactly what you're looking for. Each of these links has an anonymous function tied to them meaning they don't have any variable tied to them except that tag's onclick value. Plus if you wanted to, you could include more lines of code this way, all grouped up in one tidy location.

Comment: You might want to ignore my answer, I created this when there was way less in the original question.

Answer (score -1):

```
function ReAssign(valautionId, userName) {
   var valautionId 
   var userName 
 alert(valautionId);
 alert(userName);
  }

<a href=# onclick="return ReAssign('valuationId','user')">Re-Assign</a>
```