# Pass multiple element from inline onclick javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, inline

Is it possible to send multiple element from inline javascript onclick function  for example like this i tried but got undefined

```
<input type='text' id='elem1'/>
<input type='text' id='elem2'/>
    <a onclick="functionName($('#elem1').val(),$('#elem2').val())"></a>
```

?

Comment: Its possible  to pass multiple element in javascript onclick function

Comment: It has been asked in the pass, [You can check it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13285489/pass-multiple-values-with-onclick-in-html-link).

Comment: i think my question was not clear but i edited hope you got my mean now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this

```
<input type='text' id='elem1'/>
<input type='text' id='elem2'/>
<a onclick="myfunc($('#elem1').val(),$('#elem2').val())"></a>
```

Javascript

```
function myfunc(val1,val2)
{
  alert(val1);
  alert(val1);
}
```

Comment: :) thanks first time i did like this but got undefined but after seeing your answer it works :)

Comment: You are welcome i guess you wouldn't have accepted agruments in function that's why got undefined

Answer (score 1):

Is it a shared function? Why not just access the values from inside the actual function?

Comment: the function is called from many parts  and the value of elem1 and elem2 is from some different elements this is why i tried this. and i also wandered  if it is possible to do like this  or not because i searched i didn't get any results. :)