# My onclick Javascript function get executed without clicking

Tags: javascript, onclick

I want to do some actions when a button on my page is clicked, but my function executes without clicking on the button and when I check the log using firebug I got "undefine" message. Below is my code snippet so far.

```
var email = example@example.com   
"<button class='btn btn-warning' onclick ='"+addNote(email)+"' >Add Note</button>"

function addNote(youremail){
     alert("Your email is "+ youremail);
}
```

With the above code snippet the output will be Your email is example@example.com.

Comment: See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9643311/pass-string-parameter-in-an-onclick-function. Your code is actually calling the function addNote, not inserting it into the HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because you are ***calling*** the function instead of adding it ***into*** your string.

```
"<button class='btn btn-warning' onclick ='addNote(email)' >Add Note</button>"
```

See this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/sP35v/

Comment: will this not treat the parameter as a regular string instead of a variable?

Comment: @fanbondi No, it will treat it as a variable. If email were a string your event would look like this: onclick="addNote('email')" -> See the difference?

Comment: Oh okay I got it,however in the console it says email is not define even-though I defined it before calling it.

Comment: @fanbondi Did you quote that example email address? Please see the jsfiddle link I included in my post. It will show a working version.