# how to send string parameter to javascript function

Tags: javascript, string, function, parameters

I'm trying to pass string value to javascript function but it shows syntax error.my code is below

```
product_row +='<td><input type="text" name="edit_product_type" 
id="edit_product_type_'+this.id_sale_order+'" value="'+this.product_type+'" 
onblur="updateProduct(\'' + this.id_sale_order + '\','edit');" rel="edit" />';
```

Error

```
SyntaxError: missing ; before statement
..." onblur="updateProduct(\'' + this.id_sale_order + '\','edit');" rel="edit" />'
```

Comment: Try this `var a = 'ppppppppppp'; var product_row ='<td><input type="text" name="edit_product_type" id="edit_product_type_' + a + '" value="' + a + '" onblur="updateProduct(\'' + this.id_sale_order + '\',\'edit\');" rel="edit" />';`

Answer (score 0):

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9643311/pass-string-parameter-in-an-onclick-function) answer.

Here is an example:

```
'<input type="button" onClick="gotoNode(\'' + result.name + '\')" />'
```

In your case, you probably want to pass `edit` as a string, so change this

```
product_row +='<td><input type="text" name="edit_product_type" 
id="edit_product_type_'+this.id_sale_order+'" value="'+this.product_type+'" 
onblur="updateProduct(\'' + this.id_sale_order + '\','edit');" rel="edit" />';
```

to this

```
product_row +='<td><input type="text" name="edit_product_type" 
id="edit_product_type_'+this.id_sale_order+'" value="'+this.product_type+'" 
onblur="updateProduct(\'' + this.id_sale_order + '\',\'edit\');" rel="edit" />';
```

where the escape backslashes were used.

Answer (score 0):

Check for typos:

either: `onblur="updateProduct(\'' + this.id_sale_order + '\',\''+edit+'\');"`

or: `onblur="updateProduct(\'' + this.id_sale_order + '\',\'edit\');"`

depends if edit is meant as variable name or string

Answer (score 0):

You need to type correct single quotes in onblur function like,

```
onblur="updateProduct(\"' + this.id_sale_order + '\",\"edit\");" rel="edit" />
```

You can use both single and double quotes but make sure you have done them with care

Answer (score 0):

You are missing quotes

```
    product_row +='<td><input type="text" name="edit_product_type" 
id="edit_product_type_'
+this.id_sale_order
+'" value="'
+this.product_type
+'" onblur="updateProduct(\'' 
+ this.id_sale_order 
+ '\',\'edit\');" rel="edit" />';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you break down your code you will find the problem at second last row where if you remove the word 'edit' you will not get an error and if you put it in double quotation marks you won't get an error but if you put it in single quotation mark , you will get error

```
product_row +='<td><input type="text" 
name="edit_product_type" 
id="edit_product_type_'+this.id_sale_order+'"
value="'+this.product_type+'" 
onblur="updateProduct(\'' + this.id_sale_order + '\',
```

\'edit\');" // the problem is here , so put on 'edit' with \'edit\'

```
rel="edit" />';
```