# value is taken as parameter on function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

im passing a value retrieved from an ajax call to a function like this way:

```
nuevaFila+='<td><input type="button" value="Agregar" onclick="AgregarSuvenir('+item.CODSUVENIR+');"></td></tr>';
```

and we i clicked the button it throws an undefinided "variable" but is not a variable, i just wanted to pass it as a string, and the value passed to the function is taken as a variable, i tried

```
onclick="AgregarSuvenir("'+item.CODSUVENIR+'") and onclick="AgregarSuvenir('+item.CODSUVENIR+""')
```

but this fails

someone help me how to pass the value as string and not be taken a a variable.

thanks is advance

Comment: You should check in the browser console what variable it is complaining about

Comment: *"someone help me how to pass the value as string"* Strings are delimited by quotation marks. I.e. you have to add quotation marks. The difficulties comes form the fact that you are dealing with nested sets of quotation marks.

Comment: @Andrex it's complaining about the value passed, eg. item.CODSUVENIR = SSX, so it says undefined variable SSX

Comment: You can add escaped apostrophes: `onclick="AgregarSuvenir(\''+item.CODSUVENIR+'\');"`

Comment: @ArturoHulk you just solve the issue there,  it's the variable SSX was not initialized.

Comment: @Ninsly that's right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple case of matching quotes. Because you use single quotes to delimit the string, you must add escaped quotes inside your function call in order for the inserted value to be treated like a string.

Here are two possible solutions that escape the quotations to allow for the parameter to the `AgregarSuvenir` function to be treated like a string:

```
nuevaFila+='<td><input type="button" value="Agregar" onclick="AgregarSuvenir(\''+item.CODSUVENIR+'\');"></td></tr>';
```

or:

```
nuevaFila+="<td><input type=\"button\" value=\"Agregar\" onclick=\"AgregarSuvenir('"+item.CODSUVENIR+"');\"></td></tr>";
```

Answer (score 0):

found it!

it has to be formatted like stated on this post: [pass string parameter in an onclick function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9643311/pass-string-parameter-in-an-onclick-function)

```
onclick="AgregarSuvenir(\''+item.CODSUVENIR+'\')
```