# passing parameter to function

Tags: javascript, php

I want to pass the parameter to function. If I pass ID to parameter it is working. But I want to pass string value as parameter to function. I want to add escape sequence to the parameter. If I pass `$fet['cf_id']` as parameter it is working. If I pass `$fet['file_name']` value, it is not passed.

```
$file1=$fet['file_name'];
$ef=$fet['cf_id'];
$next1 = basename($file1);
echo '<td style="text-align:center;width:100px;"><img src="image/delete1.png" alt="delete" style="width:10px;height:10px" title="Remove" onclick="myFunction('.$fet['file_name'].');"></td></tr>';
function myFunction(cid) {   
    // alert(cid);
    var  rmvfile=cid;
    //display conformation box
    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to Delete the file?") == true) {
        if(cid!='')
        {
            $.ajax({
                type:'post',
                url:'delete_cli_file.php',
                data:{rmvfile: rmvfile},
                success:function(msg){
                    if (msg.length> 0) {
                        alert(msg);
                        location.reload();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [pass string parameter in an onclick function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9643311/pass-string-parameter-in-an-onclick-function)

Comment: I want to pass php string value as parameter.

Comment: Yes, I know. That question has this answered. Basically you are missing quotes. `'<input type="button" onClick="myFunction(\''.$fet['file_name'].'\');" />'`. This will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

where you pass the text to javascript it must be in 'text'.

```
       $file1 =$fet['file_name'];
       $a     ="'";
       $ef    =$fet['cf_id'];
       $next1 = basename($file1);
       echo '<td style="text-align:center;width:100px;">
             <img src="image/delete1.png" alt="delete" 
              style="width:10px;height:10px" 
              title="Remove"
              onclick="myFunction('.$a.$fet['file_name'].$a.');">
             </td></tr>';

     function myFunction(cid)
     {   
        // alert(cid);
        var  rmvfile=cid;
        //display conformation box
        if (confirm("Are you sure you want to Delete the file?") == true)       
        {
         if(cid!='')
         {
           $.ajax({
           type:'post',
           url:'delete_cli_file.php',
           data:{rmvfile: rmvfile},
           success:function(msg)
           {
             if (msg.length> 0) 
             {
                alert(msg);
                location.reload();
             }
           }
      });
      }} }
```

Comment: Why is a quote in variable?

Comment: because you are using echo with in single quote so your output never be in 'yourtext'. to echo the ' quote you use variable check it if it is working or not once i faced the same problem so i figure this out

Comment: Backslash before `'` is just enough.

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
echo '<td style="text-align:center;width:100px;"><img src="image/delete1.png"
      alt="delete" style="width:10px;height:10px" title="Remove"
      onclick="myFunction('.$fet['file_name'].');"></td></tr>';
```

use

```
echo '<td style="text-align:center;width:100px;"><img src="image/delete1.png"
      alt="delete" style="width:10px;height:10px" title="Remove"
      onclick="myFunction(\''.$fet['file_name'].'\');"></td></tr>';
```