# Passing string parameter in JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, html, events, button, onclick

I was trying to pass a string to a JavaScript function.

As it's mentioned here - *[Pass a string parameter in an onclick function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9643311/pass-a-string-parameter-in-an-onclick-function)*

I'm using this simple code-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <body>
        <script>
            name = "Mathew";
            document.write("<button id='button' type='button' onclick='myfunction(\''" + name + "'\')'>click</button>")

            function myfunction(name)
            {
                alert(name);
            }
        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

But in the console it's giving an error like `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }`.

Comment: Any reason you're trying to add a table cell to a page without a table?

Comment: Note that the top answer to that question also recommended proper DOM methods, something you might want to consider - it would prevent these kind of issues coming up.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Change your code to

```
document.write("<td width='74'><button id='button' type='button' onclick='myfunction(\""+ name + "\")'>click</button></td>")
```

Answer (score 10):

Rename your variable `name` to `myname`, bacause `name` is a generic property of `window` and is not writable in the same window.

And replace

```
onclick='myfunction(\''" + name + "'\')'
```

With

```
onclick='myfunction(myname)'
```

Working example:

```js
var myname = "Mathew";
document.write('<button id="button" type="button" onclick="myfunction(myname);">click</button>');
function myfunction(name) {
    alert(name);
}
```

Comment: it's not printing anything in alert box if I use this code.

Comment: function myfunction(myname) {  alert(myname); }

Answer (score 6):

The question has been answered, but for your future coding reference you might like to consider this.

In your HTML, add the name as an attribute to the button and remove the onclick reference.

```
<button id="button" data-name="Mathew" type="button">click</button>
```

In your JavaScript, grab the button using its ID, assign the function to the button's `click` event, and use the function to display the button's data-name attribute.

```
var button = document.getElementById('button');

button.onclick = myfunction;

function myfunction() {
  var name = this.getAttribute('data-name');
  alert(name);
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/1s0z45me/8/)

Answer (score 6):

```
document.write(`<td width='74'><button id='button' type='button' onclick='myfunction(\``+ name + `\`)'>click</button></td>`)
```

Better to use `` than "". This is a more dynamic answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass string parameters to JavaScript functions like below code:

I passed three parameters where the third one is a string parameter.

```
var btn ="<input type='button' onclick='RoomIsReadyFunc(" + ID + "," + RefId + ",\"" + YourString + "\");'  value='Room is Ready' />";

// Your JavaScript function

function RoomIsReadyFunc(ID, RefId, YourString)
{
    alert(ID);
    alert(RefId);
    alert(YourString);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this ...

```js
onclick="myfunction('name')";
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
document.write('<td width="74"><button id="button" type="button" onclick="myfunction('" + name + "')">click</button></td>')
```

Comment: document.write('<td width="74"><button id="button" type="button" onclick="myfunction('" + name + "')">click</button></td>')