# Add function to onclick with String parameter that contains HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to add a function in an onclick with 3 parameters: int, int, string. The string parameter that contains an HTML and other quotations. Would it be possible?. I saw it here [pass string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9643311/pass-string-parameter-in-an-onclick-function) but it is not working on my case.

```
 <p onclick="myfunction(0,3,'<b">FirstName =
 \"Dondellx\"\n<b>LastName</b> = \"Batacx\"\n<b>path</b> = 
 \"xxxpath\""');dondell
 </p>
```

This function that contains the String with many \\ characters are actually from a JSON file which I put in a "p" tag in a loop when reading the JSON.

This is what i am doing to get the JSON item and put to the string param;

```
//This is a for loop
<p onclick="myfunction(0,3,'dataFromJSon[0]')"></p>
<p onclick="myfunction(0,3,'dataFromJSon[1]')"></p>
<p onclick="myfunction(0,3,'dataFromJSon[2]')"></p>
```

[image]

This is the text editor to enter my Text.
As you can see, I have quotations in the textArea, so that is why i need to save it with qoutations. :

[image]

This is the JSON:

[image]

Comment: Your question is very unclear. The html in your function is very mis-formed as well. I would assume if anything that is your issue, but you need to post more details. A jsfiddle of what you are trying to accomplish and where it is exactly failing would go a long way.

Comment: Hi @peinearydevelopment. Thanks for the comment. I have updated my question. I hope it is more clearer now. Please your welcome to add comment if it is not yet clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your html is misformed indeed, so I created a simpler demo. Hopefully it'll still be useful as I use an object to pass the html code as well as the other parameters.

```js
var object = {a:0,b:3,c:'<b>FirstName=</b>Dondellx'};
function myfunction(obj){
  document.getElementById("out").innerHTML=obj.c;
}
```

```html
<p onclick="myfunction(object)">click</p>
<div id="out"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is certainly because there are so many syntax error in you HTML and JavaScript code.

Not correctly escape quote, not escape line break inside a javascript string declaration, HTML tag not properly close, attribute value not correctly defined...

Maybe try this (I have implement a fake `myfunction` for exemple and replace `\n` by `<br/>`, the line break not make sense in HTML).

```js
function myfunction(a,b,str){
  var row = document.createElement('div');
  row.innerHTML = str;
  document.body.appendChild(row);
}
```

```html
<p onclick="myfunction(0,3,'<b>FirstName = &quot;Dondellx&quot<br/><b>LastName</b> = &quot;Batacx&quot;<br/><b>path</b> = &quot;xxxpath&quot;');">dondell
</p>
```