# Passing a php variable with with string qiuotes in js function

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to pass a php variable inside js function but I am getting the following error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Here's my code:

```
<?php 
$author ="James Wilson";

echo '<li  onClick= getAuthor("'.$author.'");>';

?>
```

Comment: Can you show the whole errormessage?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pass string parameter in an onclick function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9643311/pass-string-parameter-in-an-onclick-function)

Comment: Try this `'<li  onClick="getAuthor(\''.$author.'\');">'`

Comment: This is not the duplicate of the link you posted @splash58.. please check carefully.

Comment: @IsmailRBOUH, I tried this.. I get same error

Comment: That code you provided shouldn't be giving you that error. It would at least generate this html: `<li onclick="getAuthor("James" wilson");></li>`

Comment: @Philipp, this is the only error message I am getting in my console.

Comment: @FirstOne, it does convert it to James Wilson (As per the source screen on my webpage). But the error is still there..

Comment: `echo '<li  onClick= "getAuthor(\'' . $author . '\')";>';` - https://eval.in/607228

Comment: But [it's fine...](https://eval.in/607227)

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ It's not fine. must be `onclick="(quote!)something(quote!)"`

Comment: @Stranger have you seen my link ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know that you need to pass a string to `onClick` attribute. In plain html it should be:

```
<li onClick="getAuthor('someone')">
```

Construct this with proper escape characters in php.

```
echo '<li  onClick= "getAuthor(\'' . $author . '\')";>';
```

Comment: I tried the exct code you shared but instead of printing James Wilson, it prints $author

Comment: Works, thank you very much. Got to know where I went wrong

Comment: Please see my first snippet. That is how your echoed php value should look like. So, you needed to construct it with proper escape characters.

Answer (score 2):

```
echo "<li onclick=\"getAuthor('$author')\">";
```

Comment: I tried this: Getting this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$author' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ',' or ';'

Comment: That should work. Another way would be `echo '<li  onclick="getAuthor(\'' . $author . '\')">';`