# How to pass parameters to JavaScript Function From Generated HTML

Tags: javascript, html, string, concatenation, generated

```
    var html = html + "<tr>\n" + "<td style='text-align: center; background-color: #FFCE43;
'> </br>" + $(n).find("Julio").text() + " <img   style = 'cursor: pointer;' onclick='myFunction('"+a+"')' src='add.png'></td> </tr>";
```

I'm trying to pass the a as parameter but no success, i'm having trouble with combination of "", ''.

Comment: What error do you get if any? Look at your console output

Comment: possible duplicate of [pass string parameter in an onclick function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9643311/pass-string-parameter-in-an-onclick-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace with below code will work.

```
var html = html + "<tr>\n" + "<td style='text-align: center; background-color: #FFCE43;
'> </br>" + $(n).find("Julio").text() + " <img   style = 'cursor: pointer;' onclick='myFunction(\""+a+"\", \""+b+"\")' src='add.png'></td> </tr>";
```