# Passing a javascript variable into an inline html onclick function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Im trying to pass a variable into an inline onclick function but without success. i've tried searching and i followed this but with errors(Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list) : 
[pass string parameter in an onclick function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9643311/pass-string-parameter-in-an-onclick-function)

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(e) {
infoWindow.setContent(data.name+ "<br> '<input type="button"onClick="Myfunction(\'' + data.name + '\')" />');
infoWindow.open(map, marker);
});
```

I want to pass data.name results inside My function(data.name);

Another thing that i want to process this result inside myfunction to load an image from Mysql php database shall i use Ajax?

Comment: Your string is malformed in `infoWindow.setContent` method.

Comment: Like @31piy said, correct your string
`'<br><input type="button" onClick="Myfunction(' + data.name + ')" />'`

Comment: Not only is the code broken, but it is unclear what the goal is here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was caused because your string was invalid:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(e) {

    var contentString = '<h3>'+data.title+'</h3></br><input type="button"onClick="Myfunction(' +data.title+ ')" />';

    infoWindow.setContent(contentString);                
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
infoWindow.setContent(data.name+ "<input type=button onClick=Myfunction("+ data.name +") />");
```