# JS Create object, added onclick function. Function fired at will right at creation

Tags: javascript, object, dom, onclick

I have a following code:

```
document.body.onload = addElement;

function addElement () {    var myImage = new Image(400, 100); 
myImage.src = 'https://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2017/holidays-2017-day-2-5240850203279360-s.png'; 
myImage.id = "myImageId";   
myImage.onclick = myVerySpecialFunction(); 
document.body.appendChild(myImage);   
var tmp = "myVerySpecialFunctionAnswer()";   
document.getElementById("myImageId").setAttribute("onclick", tmp); } 

function myVerySpecialFunction() {  alert("Knock-knock!"); } 
function myVerySpecialFunctionAnswer() { alert("Who is there!?"); }
```

When I add to my myImage.onclick function, it fired instantly. Why does it do that? Could I prevent it?
Of course, I can do a workaround here with setAttribute, but I don't like it. 
https://jsfiddle.net/kv8w78be/3/

Comment: It's because you're calling the function. Use `myImage.onclick = myVerySpecialFunction` <-- no parenthesis.

Comment: Because you're immediately calling it instead of giving it a reference of the function. Try `myImage.onclick = myVerySpecialFunction;` instead.

Comment: @Andy You both are correct. But what if I want to call my function in future with a parameter, how then I should correct describe it? https://jsfiddle.net/kv8w78be/5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Mark and Andy have stated in the comments to your question, it's due to how you are attempting to assign your function to the `onClick` event.

In JavaScript, there's a difference between calling a function and assignment a function to property. For example,

```js
let myImage = new Image(400, 100);
function foo() { console.log(Hello, world!); }

myImage.onclick = foo(); // As foo() does not return any value, myImage.onclick is set to undefined.
myImage.onclick = foo; // myImage.onclick is set as a reference to function foo().
```

When you assign `foo()` to the `onClick` event, what you are actually saying is 'Assign the value that function `foo()` returns to `myImage.onclick`. As such, the function is immediately called.

You instead want to assignment `foo`, without the parenthesis. This makes `myImage.onclick` reference the function `foo()`, making it so the function is called when the `onClick` event occurs.

Comment: But what if I want to call my function in future with a parameter, how then I should correct describe it? jsfiddle.net/kv8w78be/5 I would like to have a parameter. With parenthesis on setAttribute I could get this behaviour.

Comment: @Areso That's an entirely different question, but in short, you would want to use `addEventListener()` instead of assigning directly the to event hook. Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9643311/pass-string-parameter-in-an-onclick-function) for more on that.

Comment: @Areso, why are you trying to add two functions to that element? You add one to the element with `onclick`, then try and add another one _to the same element_ with `setAttribute`.

Comment: @Andy I did it with an intention. First time (via object) to show what I try to fix, second time (via setAttribute) to show what I try to achieve. As Jeffrey suggests, I looked to another answer, and what's I want achievable either via setAttribute (and I did it correct), or via addEventListener (I completely was not familiar with that approach in JS).

Answer (score 1):

It is fired instantly because the JavaScript interpreter reads `myVerySpecialFunction()` which is a function call and then attempts to assign the returned value to the onclick event.

The correct way to achieve your desired behaviour would be to assign the function `myVerySpecialFunction` to your event. and not a function call.

It can be done this way :

```
document.body.onload = addElement;

function addElement () {    var myImage = new Image(400, 100); 
myImage.src = 'https://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2017/holidays-2017-day-2-5240850203279360-s.png'; 
myImage.id = "myImageId";   
myImage.onclick = myVerySpecialFunction; 
document.body.appendChild(myImage);   
} 

function myVerySpecialFunction() {  alert("Knock-knock!"); }
```

Here : https://jsfiddle.net/scubatank115/1gjp8w2o/3/