# insert a value in function variable

Tags: javascript

is there any way that i can pass a variable in function in the @click function. this is what i intend to do.

```
<div @click="someFunction(type=clockIn)"
  <p>some template</p>
</div>
```

in a html template. how can i define the variable with its value. because i have 3 template where when i click on it will on it, the  someFunction will trigger and using the type value.
the function is not a problem. the problem is how to define the type variable with its value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9643311/pass-string-parameter-in-an-onclick-function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, you can just pass it into the onClick -

HTML >>>>

```
<p onclick="myFunction(myVariable)">
```

JS >>>>>

```
function myFunction(e){
    console.log(e);
}

var myVariable = 'Variable'
```

Result >>>>

```
Variable
```

:)

Comment: yeahh at first i don't know why can't i brainstorm the logic. maybe it's too much thing i need to think. a while after i post this question just i remembered.

Comment: staring at a screen all day has that effect - the knowedge is there just needed another coffee to come out and play

Answer (score 1):

i don't know why my brain do not function properly before. here i share the working code that i have made

```
<div @click="someFunction('clockIn')"
  <p>some template</p>
</div>
```