# ReferenceError. How do I define a variable from json array?

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

With AJAX I am getting data from a db sent back to the website as an json array. I get to put the result out to be displayed, but when I am going to use the data further, it says ReferenceError. *variable* is not defined. I can't  see what I am doing wrong.
I am supposed to use the data from a object to put it as a parameter in a button for deleting (later), but in the code below I tried just to get the data inside the alert function to see if it worked. But somehow that does not work. 

Here is my main code: (English is not my programming language. Sorry. Tried to translate what was possible)

```
        function find()
        {
           url = "tjener-kode.php";
              $.get(url,function(data){
              var html="";

                var dataen=JSON.parse(data);
                  console.log(dataen);

                  var postnumber="";
                  var postplace="";
                  for (var a=0; a < dataen.length; a++){

                    postnumber=dataen[a].postnr;
                    postplace=dataen[a].poststed;
                    html+="Postplace: "+postplace+" Postnumber: "+postnumber+" <button onClick=alarm("+dataen[a]["poststed"]+")>Test</button><br>";
                  }
                  $("#respons2").html(html);
           });
        }
        function alarm(postplace){
          alert("Hello. You clicked on  "+postplace);
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="respons2"></p>
      <button onClick="find()">Bring all postcodes</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

For the button I have tried different code with the same error result:

```
<button onClick=alarm("+postplace+")>
<button onClick=alarm("+dataen[a]["poststed"].value+")>
```

Here is my server code tjener-kode.php:

```
<?php
$db = new mysqli("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
if($db->connect_error)
{
    die("Error");
}
$sql = "Select * from postnrPoststed";
    $resultat = $db->query($sql);

    $data=array();

    while($rad=mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultat)){
      $data[]=$rad;
    }
    echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Using console log you can see that the result is this. And this is correct:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9m9b.png)

But when clicking the button at the webpage belonging to each object, with the supposedly defined variable, I get this error in the console:

It says that the variable is not defined, but somehow I still get the data in the variable shown in the console log. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BKeNr.png)

Comment: In the developers tools console, if you click on the error - to which line does it refer?

Comment: Using chrome I got this: Uncaught ReferenceError: Oslo is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):1)

Comment: Why do you have to parse the data? What's the format when you just access the `tjener-kode.php` file in your browser? If the resulting format is json, you just have to access by `data.keyname`.

Comment: I just used parse because that was the only way I got it to be displayed the data. Do you know a better way? The only code on the tjener-kode.php is displayed above. And accessing the page on the server it looks like this: [{"postnr":"0166","poststed":"Oslo"},{"postnr":"4821","poststed":"Rykene"}]

Comment: What's the url for this file `tjener-kode.php`? Access it in your browser.

Comment: I just tried it without parsing. Now everything is underfined, and the for loop just looped over 10 lines. That is not working at all :)

Comment: I dont think I should share the url, but here is how it looks like. Everything is hosted on the school server: https://imgshare.io/image/nettt22.KtUtt

Comment: save `data = data[0]` and try not parsing it, and access it like this `data.postnr`.

Comment: That resulted in a almost endless loop. Thought and looks like I have to parse it so that javascript can handle the object. https://imgshare.io/image/ff.KgYZw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. Here is the best answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9643494/12867645

Since I am using javascript to make the button, I have to append it to the paragraph. I tried the same code under inside the html+="" with and without ' , but that didn't work. So you have to append it. or document.write().

```
$( "#respons" ).append('<input type="button" value="test" onclick="alarm(\'' + postsplace + '\')" />');
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because `<button onClick=alarm("+dataen[a]["poststed"]+")>` will already give you value that you need.You don't need to use `.value`

Comment: But I want the "poststed" (name in database) as the value in the parameter.

Comment: I have tried everything. Without the paramter/argument the function works fine. But it is somehow something wrong with the way I pass the argument. Using the same argument to display it on the website works fine, but not when I am using the same name into the function. I dont know why