# How to pass multiple argument in js function with single quote

Tags: javascript, datatable

I am trying to pass parameters to function using single quote however it is showing error due to missing quote but I am unable to figure out where it is I am using inside datatable

```
onclick="assign_id(' + aData['id'] + ',string value' + ')"





expected output:
     onclick="assign_id('dbvalue','string')"

 "fnCreatedRow": function (nRow, aData, iDataIndex)
            {
    var action_link = '<a class="dropdown-item" onclick="assign_id(' + aData['db value here'] + ',' some string here ')">Delivered</a>';
},
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass a string parameter in an onclick function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9643311/pass-a-string-parameter-in-an-onclick-function)

Comment: @ShahnawazHossan I am unable to get how to place this, could u write here with above requirement

Comment: Everything within double quotes is just a string. Instead of using `onclick` attribute, i suggest that you use `element.addEventListener('click', ...)` to add the click event listener.

Comment: this should work onclick="assign_id(aData[id], '2')"

Comment: Don't use inline event handlers. It's widely considered insecure, bad coding and causes exactly these problems. The same is true for creating HTML from a string.

Comment: Look at your onclick function. It is currently `assign_id( ' + aData['id'] + ',string value' + ' )`. If you don't see anything wrong, read this again and try matching the quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this should work?

```
var action_link = '<a class="dropdown-item" onclick="assign_id(\'' + aData['db value here'] + '\', \'' + 2 + '\')">Delivered</a>';
```

Or using template strings

```
onclick=`assign_id('${aData['id']}',2)`;
```

Comment: @ashue it is missinging single quote and showing some error

Comment: can you please at least put up some code in the context of a function? so that we can answer better, try the literal type, maybe it can help, avoid the semicolons at end

Comment: var action_link = '<a class="dropdown-item" onclick="assign_id(' + aData['db value here'] + ', your db var )">Delivered</a>';

Comment: @ Ashu still getting error unexpected token beacuse values should be get enclosed inside single quote properly

Comment: I have updated the answer for one last time, this should be it or it's up to you afterwards :)

Comment: second argument is enclosed inside single quote perfectly could u please help me same with first argument

Comment: thank u so much u helped me a lot and given your precious time, it is working as per expectation

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what aData['id'] refers to because it's can only be a string.
Try this:

```
onclick="assign_id('aData[`id`],2')"
```