# Parameterize button bind function for wechat miniprogram

Tags: wechat-miniprogram

I'm trying with wechat miniprogram for the first time and believe its *still web pages* but with its own tag (and handling).

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
  <view class="btns">
    <button bindtap="getWeather('New York')">New York</button>
    <button bindtap="getWeather('Toronto')">Toronto</button>
  </view>
```

IE for the web page buttons, I want to call the `getWeather` function, but different buttons will pass different parameters to the function.

How can I do it in wechat miniprogram and also html/javascript in general as well please?

UPDATE:

My code in theory should work with html/javascript in general, like:

- https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_function2, or
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/38632590/2125837

So this question only limits to wechat miniprogram then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"bindtap="getWeather('New York')" ,the parameterize will not transform in normal.Wechat miniprogram use the way below:

```js
Page({
  data: {
    selectedRole: null
  },
  eventFunc(e) {
    console.log(e)
    this.setData({
      selectedRole: e.target.dataset.role
    })
  }
})
```

```html
<Button bindtap="eventFunc" data-role="teacher">teacher</Button>
<Button bindtap="eventFunc" data-role="student">student</Button>
selectedRole:{{selectedRole}}
```

Now, developing with Wechat Native language decreased a lot.More developers use other frame (use vue or react) to transform into Wechat Miniprogram Native Codes and run.