# JavaScript parse variable in quote

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript Variable inside string without concatenation - like PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304014/javascript-variable-inside-string-without-concatenation-like-php)

In PHP, double quotes has the ability to read variable, e.g.

```
"$foo"
```

But in JavaScript, you have to always use a `+` to read a variable so that the variable won't be inside the quote when it is read, e.g.

```
var foo='bar';
alert("The name's "+foo);
```

So, is there any workaround or method to do this? Using `+` all the time is quite troublesome.

Comment: `alert(["The name's ", foo].join(''));` ;)

Comment: check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408289/best-way-to-do-variable-interpolation-in-javascript

Comment: @xdazz obviously more troublesome to do that haha

Comment: @FelixKling oopss.. I'll delete this question then.

Comment: @FelixKling And it looks like I can't do it :\

Comment: Oh well... Never mind, I'll just pick an answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, that's not possible in JavaScript.

In JavaScript, variables are turned into string when put in single quotes or doubles quotes and can't be parsed. In JavaScript **everything inside quotes is treated as string**.

Even if you write **custom parser**, you will have no way to figure out if something in quotes is really a variable or an string because a variable named `name` can also appear in string somewhere which will create naming collisions.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no workaround, that's just how it is.

Javascript doesn't offer "string interpolation".

Personally I favour Ildar Shaimordanov's [`String.js`](http://code.google.com/p/jsxt/source/browse/trunk/js/String.js) module which adds a `sprintf` method to the string object.