# How to pass multiple parameter on dynamic link function jquery function C#?

Tags: javascript, c#

I have one c# web application in which put one link dynamically like,

```
if (oObj.aData[1] == '2') {                                
    Id = oObj.aData[7];
    Name = oObj.aData[2];
    alert(Name);
    return '<a href=#  onClick="Show(' + Id + ',' + Name + ');"> Show </a>'; 
    //this is        
}
```

function like,

```
function Show(id,name)
{
  alert('calling');
}
```

but my function not calling.

Is any syntax error or anything else which I forgetting?

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass `Name` in quotes(`''`), with in quotes to be treated as string parameter. Otherwise they will be treated as *JS variable* which obviously you have not defined, You must be getting error `'example string' is not defined.` in browser console.

```
return '<a href=#  onClick="Show(' + Id + ',\'' + Name + '\');"> Show </a>';
```

Note: If `Id` is a string, also pass it in quotes('')

Answer (score 0):

This may be of some help.

Starting from Firefox 34 and Chrome 41 you will be able to use an ECMAScript 6 feature called Template Strings and use this syntax:

`String text ${expression}`
Example:

```
var a = 5;
var b = 10;
console.log(`Fifteen is ${a + b}.`);
// "Fifteen is 15.
```

source: [JavaScript Variable inside string without concatenation - like PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304014/javascript-variable-inside-string-without-concatenation-like-php)

Comment: sorry but in my post i forgot write function but in my code it's written.