# Replace part of string with variable

Tags: javascript, string, replace

I have the following string:
`documentation/:docsID/items`
Now I want to replace the `:docsID` by a variable.
So if the variable is equal to `12`, i want the link look like `documentation/12/items`.
How can I accomplish this with Javascript?

Comment: You can learn some elementary [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).

Comment: `.replace(':docsID', varName)` ???

Comment: I always think SO is undermined when people post answers to questions that show no search effort. What's the point in people to do their research when they can do none and get answers anyway?

Comment: replace if it isn't a hardcoded string else use `"asdf"+12+"fdsa"`

Comment: this is a valid question. i think he just didn't state clearly what he was asking. this question should be pointed to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304014/how-to-interpolate-variables-in-strings-in-javascript-without-concatenation?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string.replace(":docsID",var)
```

To easy right? Next time try first!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var str="documentation/:docsID/items"
var val=12;
str =str.replace(":docsID",val)
```