# Why isn't my PHP echo text storing as a variable in JQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have the following input within a form:

```
<form>
    <input type="hidden" name="hiddeninput" value="SecondProblem"> 
</form>
```

Using the script below, I'm trying to store the word "SecondProblem" using PHP echo as a variable in JQuery and then use this to hide the parent form. The PHP echo text, however, is not picked up by a variable.

```
$(function(){ 
var selectorvar = "<?php echo "SecondProblem"; ?>"
var selectorvar1=selectorvar ;
 $('input[value="+selectorvar1+"]').closest("form").css("display", "none");
});
```

When I directly replace `"+selectorvar1+"` with the text `"SecondProblem"` the form display successfully switches to "none" so I know it has something to do with the PHP echo not storing as a variable.

Side note: I realize that there are simpler ways to turn the display on this form to "none" but I need to do it this way; I just removed the context so I could present my problem more directly.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Concatenate the variable, `$('input[value="' +selectorvar1+ '"]')`

Comment: Please use your browser console to check errors. Console will tell you where you have problems

Comment: @chris85 is correct, you can't expect to end `''` delimited strings with a `"`. Any sane editor will make this obvious.

Comment: @AdamWilliams more so the variable isn't expanded to its value because of the single quotes, I don't if JS does that in double quotes.

Comment: It'd only do it in a template string, AFAIK.

Comment: @Snoops .... stop changing the code in the question.... you keep changing problems

Comment: @charlietfl I changed one comma, which had nothing to do with the issue. Thanks for everyone's help!

Comment: Right...well that comma became an answer .... and your browser console would also have told you it was a problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript Variable inside string without concatenation - like PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304014/javascript-variable-inside-string-without-concatenation-like-php)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$('input[value="+selectorvar1+"]')` should be `$('input[value="'+selectorvar1+'"]')`.

Notice the single quotes added.

Comment: It worked! Thanks; it's strange, because I have a similar bit of code later on that doesn't use those extra apostrophes and it works: `var = carouselbutton1percentage = "<?php echo "47"; ?>"
var percentage=carouselbutton1percentage,
    col1="#72CF2F",
    col2="white";
var t=document.getElementById('carouselbutton1');
t.style.background = "-webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom,left top, color-stop("+percentage+"%,"+col1+"), color-stop("+percentage+"%,"+col2+"))";`

Comment: Snoops...makes no sense using `<? php echo?>` to output hard code strings

Comment: @Snoops I see no instance in your provided example where a JS variable is inside quotes.

Comment: The jQuery selector is a string... You have to "concatenate" it when you use a variable to add to. So, between the single quotes boudaries, is the string passed as a selector. To add the variable, it has to be cutted in two parts... to concatenate the variable using the `+` sign.

Comment: When you do `var = carouselbutton1percentage = "<?php echo "47"; ?>"`... There is no need for extra quote.

Comment: According to the way we've resolved my original issue, `"+percentage+"` seems like it shouldn't return the value `47` in place of `percentage` unless it were written `" '+percentage+' "`but it does.

Comment: Nope... In this part you mention, the string delimiter are double-quotes... No need for additional quotes.

Comment: for `"+percentage+"` that depends on what the quotes are that start and end the string.

Comment: Got it. Thanks so much everyone!

Comment: Yes... You have to know what a quote or a double quote limits. Is it a string... Or a inner part of that string. Like here, we had an inner part : `$('input[value="'+selectorvar1+'"]')` The double quotes are part of the outer string delimited by the singles.

Answer (score -1):

I believe

```
var selectorvar = "<?php echo "SecondProblem"; ?>",
var selectorvar1=selectorvar ;
```

Should be

```
var selectorvar = "<?php echo "SecondProblem"; ?>",
selectorvar1=selectorvar ;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried to remove `var` accordingly, but it didn't do anything, unfortunately.

Comment: There is no comma showing on first line in OP code. Missing `;` is not an issue in non minified code

Comment: No problem, also your quotes are fine. PHP is parsed by the server and won't place double quotes in your javascript.

Comment: @charlietfl there was when he created it. It's been edited.

Comment: Downvoted because this doesn't cover the concatenation issue within the jQuery call.

Comment: Yeah, I removed the comma because I have a similar segment of code that I used elsewhere without a comma and it worked. Nonetheless, it doesn't work either with the comma or without the comma.