# How to insert a variable inside a path

Tags: javascript, filepath

I am trying to add a variable inside the path to map layer.

```
mypath='MyApp'
    var Finals = L.tileLayer.wms("http://localhost:8080/geoserver/'+mypath+'/wms", {
        layers: 'MyApp:finalVector',
        format: 'image/png',
        transparent: true,
        version: '1.1.0',
        attribution: "myattribution"
    });
```

How can I add *mypath* variable inside the *Finals* variable.

After adding it should act like following

```
var Finals = L.tileLayer.wms("http://localhost:8080/geoserver/MyApp/wms", {
        layers: 'MyApp:finalVector',
        format: 'image/png',
        transparent: true,
        version: '1.1.0',
        attribution: "myattribution"
    });
```

Comment: Change `'+mypath+'` to `"+mypath+"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript Variable inside string without concatenation - like PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304014/javascript-variable-inside-string-without-concatenation-like-php)

Answer (score 1):

```
mypath='MyApp'
    var Finals = L.tileLayer.wms("http://localhost:8080/geoserver/" + mypath + "/wms", {
        layers: 'MyApp:finalVector',
        format: 'image/png',
        transparent: true,
        version: '1.1.0',
        attribution: "myattribution"
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use template literals to pass variable to string.

```
var Finals = L.tileLayer.wms(`http://localhost:8080/geoserver/${mypath}/wms`, {
  layers: 'MyApp:finalVector',
  format: 'image/png',
  transparent: true,
  version: '1.1.0',
  attribution: "myattribution"
});
```

Comment: **template literals** is an interesting thing, do we need to add any new js library for it to work?

Comment: Refer [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to know more about it.