# How do I convert html with jsx to jsx in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to have an API with returns HTML with JSX. When the HTML is loaded, I want to convert this to JSX and pass the props from my

Given this set of code:

```
import { renderToString } from "react-dom/server";
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

function MyHtml (props) {
    var apiHtml = renderToString("<div>{this.props.title}</div>");
    return (
        <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html:  apiHtml }} />
    )
}
export default MyHtml;
ReactDOM.render(
    <MyHtml title="test"/>,
    document.getElementById('test')
);
```

I want to have the output

```
<div>test</div>
```

Instead, I get

```
<div>{this.props.title}</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: i think this will help you: [How to put variable in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304014/how-to-interpolate-variables-in-strings-in-javascript-without-concatenation)

Comment: JSX just get's transpiled to actual js code when it's built with webpack. To create components from a string dynamically you should look @ the react top-level api (Specifically `React.createElement`). See https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-jsx.html

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is:

```
var apiHtml = renderToString(`<div>{${this.props.title}}</div>`);
```

Using template literals to fill in the code you want.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing something like this:

```
var { title } = this.props; // => testing
var html = ReactDOMServer.renderToString("<div>${title}</div>");
var toRender = eval('`'+html +'`');
```

To give the output:

```
<div>testing</div>
```

Thanks everyone!