# How to pass variables in node js?

Tags: node.js

Here I'm passing `id` which stored in `m`, please help me how to pass `id`. and call that page using that `id`. I'm using the embedded JavaScript template as a view engine please help.

```
   $.each(products, function(index, product ) {

            var m= product['_id'];
            //document.write(alert(m));
            string += '<tr><td>'+(index+1)+'</td><td>'+product['_id']+'</td><td>'+product['name']+'</td><td>'+product['category']+'</td><td>'+product['price']+'</td><td>'+product['manufacturer']+'</td><td><a href="/profile/dashboard/update/{{m}}">Update</a> </td></tr>';
        });
```

> route code

```
 app.get('/profile/dashboard/update/:m',function (req,res,next) {
       console.log("hi"+req.params.m); 
      });
```

Comment: Please explain more what you want exactly, as of now your code seems to be good.

Comment: When  i click on upadte button id is not passing in the url which is the major concern here'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string += '<tr><td>'+(index+1)+'</td><td>'+product['_id']+'</td><td>'+product['name']+'</td><td>'+product['category']+'</td><td>'+product['price']+'</td><td>'+product['manufacturer']+'</td><td><a href="profile/dashboard/update/'+id+'">Update</a> </td></tr>';
```

It will work

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this quotes `` for template string;

as example:

```
var m = 1;
var string = `id: ${m}`
```

Answer (score 0):

`` `...  <a href=/profile/dashboard/update/${product['id']}>Update</a> </td></tr>` ``

You need to wrap your whole *string* in backticks and pass the variables as written above  ( *${var_name}* ). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28088965/5093377) for more info. This isn't a NodeJS question, more of a Javascript question itself.