# how to print variable alongside text using .text()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to print a variable alongside text using .text?

This is my code currently but it doesn't seem to work

```
var rowCount = $('#result li').length;
$('#count').text((rowCount)"results for");
```

thanks for your help

Comment: `$('#count').text(rowCount+" results for")` or using ES6 template literals `$('#count').text(\`${rowCount} results for\`)`

Comment: @connexo nice one, thank you

Comment: What is jquery?

Comment: Note that this isn't really about how `.text()` works, it's about how to concatenate values together. So the same solutions will apply for use in other situations including calling other functions, variable assignments, etc.

Comment: You can even do both in one line: `$('#count').text(\`${$('#result li').length} results for\`)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to interpolate variables in strings in JavaScript, without concatenation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304014/how-to-interpolate-variables-in-strings-in-javascript-without-concatenation)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this :

```
var rowCount = $('#result li').length;
alert($('#count').text(rowCount+"results for"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes sure it's possible. If I understand you correctly you want the variable printed along with some text.

```
var rowCount = $('#result li').length;
$('#count').text(rowCount + " results for");
```

or es6

```
var rowCount = $('#result li').length;
$('#count').text(`${rowCount} results for`);
```