# How to download a .vcf file in iOS WKWebView app to save it into iPhone's contacts directly?

Tags: ios, node.js, wkwebview

I already have the `.vcf` file saved on my local server `(node.js)` and am running the `WKWebView` on my iPhone as an iOS application. How can I download the `.vcf` file from the `WKWebView` app to my iPhone's contacts? When I try downloading the file on an actual browser, it works, but it doesn't work on the iOS `WKWebView` app. Maybe, is there something like a download listener for iOS, similar to the one for android? Any help will be deeply appreciated. Stuck on it for quite long!! Thanks a ton!

Comment: What do you mean by "iOS WKWebView app"?

Comment: It basically means loading my website in an iOS application. It's an updated version of the uiWebView that Swift used to have earlier.

Comment: This is the link to the documentation- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview#declarations

It describes it as "an object that displays interactive web content, such as for an in-app browser."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Part 1: Get VCF file URL from Website**

Set script message handler on `WKWebView`, use below code when initialising `WKWebView`:

```
webView?.configuration.userContentController.add(self, name: "MyHandler")
```

You have to set `WKScriptMessageHandler` delegate.

Add below code to your website's download button click event:

```
window.webkit.messageHandlers.MyHandler.postMessage({"message":"Start Download", "vcf_url":"https://www.yourwebsite.com/path/file.cvf"})
```

`didReceiveScriptMessage` will called when user clicked on download button on website. Here you will receive `["message":"Start Download", "vcf_url":"https://www.yourwebsite.com/path/file.cvf"]` object.

**Part 2: Get VCF file data and Add to Contacts**

```
func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
        print(message.body)
        if let dic = message.body as? [String:String] {
            if let url = dic["vcf_url"] {
            let fileUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: url)
            do {
                let data = try Data(contentsOf: fileUrl)
                let contacts = try CNContactVCardSerialization.contacts(with: data)
                let contactStore = CNContactStore.init()
                contactStore.requestAccess(for: CNEntityType.contacts, completionHandler: { (granted, accessError) -> Void in
                    if granted {
                        let saveRequest = CNSaveRequest()
                        for contact in contacts {
                            let newContact = CNMutableContact()
                            newContact.givenName = contact.givenName
                            newContact.familyName = contact.familyName
                            newContact.phoneNumbers = contact.phoneNumbers
                            saveRequest.add(newContact, toContainerWithIdentifier: "")
                            do {
                                try contactStore.execute(saveRequest)
                                // Contact saved successfully
                            } catch let error {
                                print("Error - \(error.localizedDescription)")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                })
            } catch let error {
                print("Error - \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }        
    }
```

Here, `newContact.imageData = contact.imageData` can be used to save image if it is not `nil`.

I have not illustrated all the property of contact in example, but you can use as you like.

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, could you please share on how to "Load the vcf file content in 'data' object"?

Right now it gives me an error saying "Use of unresolved identifier 'data'; did you mean 'Data'?", so could you please share how can I resolve this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: The onclick event for the javascript side code also doesnt seem to be working.

Snap of my website code (javascript)- "window.webkit.messageHandlers.MyHandler.postMessage({"message":"Start Download", "vcf_url":"./public/images/'User Onescan0.vcf"})"

In the vcf_url, I specified the exact path of my .vcf file stored on my local server. Also, it doesn't show the "Start Download" message anywhere.

Comment: That means something wrong on `WKWebKit` initialization part or may be `WKScriptMessageHandler ` delegate not implemented properly. Show your code for initialization of `WKWebkit`.

Comment: Oh No! You have initialized WKWebView from storyboard, so you have to change "let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        configuration.userContentController.add(self, name: "MyHandler")" to `webView?.configuration.userContentController.add(self, name: "MyHandler")`. Also add this before load request.

Comment: Now it displays the 'message' and 'vcf_url' as shown in the attached image link, however, it still doesn't save the vCard info (.vcf file) into my phone's contacts. Basically, how do I get the .vcf file into phone, and save it as a contact? I can't seem to locate the .vcf file in my phone as well. Image link to the print console in Xcode- https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWFHi.png

Comment: This is how my 'User Onescan0.vcf' file looks like- https://i.stack.imgur.com/acIMr.png

Comment: Are you getting any error? Add print statement after `try contactStore.execute(saveRequest)` line, so you can check process completed or not.

Comment: I checked with the print statement after try contactStore.execute(saveRequest) line, and it doesn't print anything, so the process is not getting completed. What could be the reason for this?

Comment: Just add break point at `print(message.body)` then use `F6` key to check app flow, check from where control is exiting?

Comment: I actually checked by putting print statements at different positions in the code, so this is the link to code- https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAPfX.png        And this is the link to the output of the code- https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJGzW.png

Comment: Error comes while creating URL from your path string. Your URL string is invalid, use full path like http://127.0.0.1/images/file.vcf

Comment: Yeah I tried changing the path quite a lot, but it's still not working fine. I am attaching the screenshot of where exactly my .vcf file is located here- https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFC8O.png
      Also, I am attaching the screenshot of the vcf_url I have mentioned in my javascript- https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dz6S.png            Since I am running using my IP address locally, am I specifying the path correctly even or no? I tried quite a lot of combinations but none seem to work. Please help me check. Thanks!!

Comment: Like what would you think the valid URL string would be in this case?

Comment: I figured the error in the previous one! There was a 'space' in the file name so it didn't read the full url. However, fixed that now, and it still showing an error but it executes more lines of code. I have attached the screenshot of the error here- https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3aC5.png    And the code is attached here- https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3Txg.png

Comment: try to create URL with this: `if let fileUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: url) {` , also you need to add Contact permission in info.plist

Comment: I tried it, and it gives an error- "Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'URL'" . Attaching the screenshot here- https://i.stack.imgur.com/pifEZ.png

Comment: I tried using 'file://' befoe specifying the absolute path of the file URL on my system, so now it gives an error saying - 'The file 'UserOneScan0.vcf' cannot be opened as there is no such file.' However, the file exists for sure and when I open the file path via my javascript code, it is able to open. What might be the error in this case?

Comment: Could you please help me with how to open a file by specifying its path in Swift? It seems that it is unable to locate the file even though it exists. Thanks!

Comment: I tried using your previous code, with a very minor change, on emulator, and it worked well i.e. I was able to save the .vcf file as a contact on the emulator. However, when I tried it on my iPhone, it didn't work and gave the me the same error- "The file UserOnescan0.vcf' couldn't be opened because there is no such file." I gave the Contacts usage permission as well in info.plist. Is there any other permission or code required to save the .vcf file as a contact on actual iPhone rather than just the emulator? Here is the link to the code- "https://i.stack.imgur.com/61BTX.png" .

Comment: Also, here is the screenshot of the error- "https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdUEi.png" . I have also printed the complete path name of .vcf file for your reference. Since this code worked perfectly on emulator, but not working on my iPhone, it means that the file actually exists, it's just it's not reading for the actual iPhone. Could you please help me resolve this? Thanks!

Comment: I tried the updated code you posted above, but that doesn't seem to work as well, and it gives the same error, even for emulator, so the previous one you posted was better in the sense that it worked for emulator.

Comment: This is because emulator can access files of your mac, but iPhone can't.

Comment: Oh okay! So how do I get to access the .vcf file on my iPhone?

Comment: For testing purpose you can use any server for eg. XAMPP, and make sure iPhone and mac both are in the same network domain.

Comment: I am already using a server using node.js, which also makes sure that my mac and iPhone are connected to the same network, then only the application runs. When I open my webpage on my iPhone's safari browser, I am able to read the contents of the .vcf file which is indeed stored locally on my mac. However, when I try to read the contents of .vcf file from the iOS application on my iPhone, it is unable to do so. What could be the reason for such a difference, and how to resolve it, since both are running on my iPhone itself?

Comment: I've been working on it continuously, however, it's still not working on iPhone. Could you please guide me on how to make it work on iPhone and save it as a contact in iPhone? Thanks a ton!

Comment: Just a quick question, how to add a variable name inside the line: "window.webkit.messageHandlers.MyHandler.postMessage({"message":"Start Download", "vcf_url":"https://www.yourwebsite.com/path/file.cvf", "name": someVariable})" in javascript. Say I have a variable in my html code and I want to send it to swift using the above line, how do I add the variable here? Thanks a lot!

Comment: see answer at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304014/how-to-interpolate-variables-in-strings-in-javascript-without-concatenation