# Variable not returing data to browser in NODE

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, node-modules

I am new in nodeJs When I try to return variable data to the server it's returning to a variable as a string.

Here is my **app.js** code

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var dataFile = require('./data/data');
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);


app.get('/', (req, res) =>{
    console.log(dataFile);
    var info= '';
    dataFile.friends.forEach(function(item){

        info +='<li><h2>${item.name}</h2><p>${item.summary}</p></li>';
    });
    console.log(info)
    res.send("<h1>MMS</h1>${info}");
});
var Server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
    console.log('listen to port '+app.get('port'));
});
```

Here is my **data.json** code

```
{
  "friends": [{
    "title" : "Class Friend",
    "name": "Ajay Negi",
    "shortname" : "Ajay",
    "summary" : "Intro",
    "description": "<p>Ajay was born in D.Dun </p>"
  },{
    "title" : "Best Friend ",
    "name": "Manpreet",
    "shortname" : "Manpreet",
    "summary": "Intro",
    "description": "<p>Manpreet was born in D.dun</p>"
  },{
    "title" : "ME",
    "name": "Vijay",
    "shortname" : "V.J",
    "summary": "INTRO",
    "description": "<p>Vijay was born in D.dun</p>"

  }]
}
```

When I run my browser its showing

[image]

In place of data
If I am using js method to make li without $ and retun only info var than its working as I expected...

Comment: yes, it is, I have checked with console it's working...

Comment: `"<h1>MMS</h1>${info}"` is a plain string, it's not a string literal that does interpolation if given `${info}`. You need to surround this in backticks `\`` instead of quotes.

Comment: You're passing back strings, not processing or parsing has happened to those strings. You're not concatinating them, and if you're trying to use interpolated strings, you have to use backticks ``` instead of single quotes `'`

Comment: Useful reading: [How to interpolate variables in strings in JavaScript, without concatenation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304014/how-to-interpolate-variables-in-strings-in-javascript-without-concatenation/)

Comment: Yes... you are right I am passing this as a string.. Thanks @VLAZ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `res.send("<h1>MMS</h1>${info}");` to

```
res.send(`<h1>MMS</h1>${info}`);
```

Read more about template strings [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Comment: Glad I can help.