# How to send a query parameter in axios Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, post, axios

This is my postman request:

```
http/localhost:8080/sample-market/marketAPI/1234/product/publish?productOne=testing&productTwo=checking
```

Can anyone help me with how to do a post call through axios. productOne & productTwo are query param & 1234 is path parameter

Comment: You mean like insert variables into a string?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to interpolate variables in strings in JavaScript, without concatenation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304014/how-to-interpolate-variables-in-strings-in-javascript-without-concatenation)

Answer (score 2):

**I think you should read the DOC first:**

**From :** https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios

Your given URL **looks like get method**:

```
http/localhost:8080/sample-market/marketAPI/1234/product/publish?productOne=testing&productTwo=checking
```

But if you still want to use **POST**, then here you go :

```
axios.post('http/localhost:8080/sample-market/marketAPI/1234/product/publish', {
    productOne: 'testing',
    productTwo: 'checking'
  })
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

---

**For GET method** :

```
axios.get('http/localhost:8080/sample-market/marketAPI/1234/product/publish', {
    params: {
      productOne: 'testing',
      productTwo: 'checking'
    }
})

//OR direct

axios.get('http/localhost:8080/sample-market/marketAPI/1234/product/publish?productOne=testing&productTwo=checking')
```

Comment: So why post an answer then?

Comment: updating as per url, so he can get idea, nothing else

Comment: yes its completely fine to have a post call without any body

Comment: @Singh, in that case, you should use GET method, POST word is for that means you are about to post , and GET is for to get data

Comment: ok can you plz explain me , what is the need of query param? i have given an API which has query param and its a post call! that post has an empty body with the two query params

Comment: @Singh, in that case you need to change the API, and if not API then just pass whole URL without params

Comment: hey, is this URL correct? `${this.ENDPOINT}/${id}/product/publish/tst` with respect to http/localhost:8080/sample-market/marketAPI/1234/product/publish/tst. ENDPOINT is "sample-market/marketAPI/"