# JavaScript property of null, pass value to the var

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having a problem with removing content from the form on Safari and IE.
I have tried to do that via CSS vith no success.
Then I tried to do it by JS but stucked here.

The Task is for current user with class user-id-1 to hide some form options.

So when I try

```
console.log(document.querySelector("option[value='+newTime+']"));
```

it returns null

```js
formID = ['1015', '1018', '1035', '1036', '1060'];
    
if (document.querySelector("body").classList.contains("user-id-1")) {
    
for (var i = 0; i < formID.length; i++) {
        var newTime = formID[i];
                
    console.log(document.querySelector("option[value='+newTime+']"));// returns null
    console.log(formID[i]);// works well
    console.log(newTime);//works well
       }
  
}
```

```html
<body class=" js user-id-1 user-role-administrator  contact_page_cf7-data auto-fold">
  <div class="user-1">
    <form>
      <select name="fid" onchange="this.form.submit();">
        <option value="">Choose form</option>
        <option value="814">Contact form 1</option>
        <option value="818">Forma za započet izazov</option>
        <option value="824">Besplatan video / prijava</option>
        <option value="981">Forma za započet izazov / Vladimir Vukadinovic</option>
        <option value="982">Besplatan video / prijava-Vladimir Vukadinovic</option>
        <option value="1001">Besplatan video / Dajana Salvati</option>
        <option value="1002">Forma za započet izazov/ Dajana Salvati</option>
        <option value="1015">Besplatan video / Raskovici</option>
        <option value="1018">Forma za započet izazov / Raskovici</option>
        <option value="1035" selected="selected">Besplatan video / Lamos</option>
        <option value="1036">Forma za započet izazov / Lamos</option>
        <option value="1060">Besplatan video / Skorici</option>
        <option value="1063">Forma za započet izazov / Skorici</option>
      </select>
    </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Your code looks for an `<option>` element with literally the value `selectedForm`. Such an option doesn't exist. [How to interpolate variables in strings in JavaScript, without concatenation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3304014/218196)

Comment: Also you need () on remove: `document.querySelector("option[value="+selectedForm+"]").remove();`

Comment: Also `if (document.querySelector("body").classList.contains("user-id-1")) ...`

Comment: you could listen to your `select` will be more efficient

Comment: Here is a workign script: `if (document.querySelector("body").classList.contains("user-id-1")) {
  const sel = document.querySelector(".user-1 select[name=fid]");
  const options = [...document.querySelectorAll(".user-1 select[name=fid] option")].filter(opt => !formID.includes(opt.value));
  if (sel.options.length > options.length) {
    sel.options.length=0; /* remove all */
    options.forEach(opt => sel.append(opt));
  }  
}
`

Comment: Thanks, @mplungjan your code work perfectly but it is too complicated for me.
Is there any easier way with just something like:
`document.querySelector("option[value='+newTime+']")).remove();`

Comment: If you format my code it is not complicated at all. It is a simple filter and I test to see if we should modify the select by comparing the length of the filter with the length of the selects options

Comment: Thank you @mplungjan