# How to run a function in input tags value attribute

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an html page that i send to a client as response when he wants to transfer money

```
response.end(
            ` 
            <!doctype html>
            <html lang="en">
            <head>
                <meta charset="utf-8">
                <title>The Good Server</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <p>Transfer money to other users with the super safe form which uses the latest HTTP GET method!</p>
                <form action="/money_transfer" method="get">
                    <div class="container">
                        <label for="from"><b>Tranfer from</b></label>
                        <input type="text" value="good_user" name="from" required readonly>
                        <label for="to"><b>Transfer to</b></label>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="User you want to send money to" name="to" required>
                        <label for="sum"><b>Sum to transfer (in full Euros)</b></label>
                        <input type="number" placeholder="Enter a sum" name="sum" required>
                        <input name="csrf_token" type="hidden" value="setCSRFtoken()">
                        <button type="submit">Transfer money</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </body>
            </html>
            `
        );
```

I try to get the an randomly generated token and set it as a **value** for the input tag as is shown before the button: **Transfer money.** My setCSRFtoken function also stores the token into an array.

```
const setCSRFtoken = () => {
   var result           = '';
   var characters       = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
   var charactersLength = characters.length;
   for ( var i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
       result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
   }
   console.log(result)
   csrfTokens.push(result);
   return result;
```

The value that returns from the setCSRFtoken function **must** be placed in to the input's(name=crsf_token) value.

The problem is that at the moment i cant get the function to run in the page and return the randomly generated value. i also thought about adding the value as parameter to the page but dont know how add it to the response.

```
<input name="csrf_token" type="hidden" onload="this.value=setCSRF()">
```

Saw the code above as an fix but it didn't work for me

Comment: Use string interpolation: `<input name="csrf_token" type="hidden" value="${setCSRFtoken()}">`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304014/how-to-interpolate-variables-in-strings-in-javascript-without-concatenation Note that _any_ valid expression can be interpolated, not just variable names.

Comment: didnt know it was called interpolation so didnt find the post but ty