# How to append a variable value in dynamically appended HTML in JS/Jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am appending a div and its children in HTML dynamically as below -

```
var x = 25;
document.getElementById("items").innerHTML += 
        `<div class="details">
          <p>Name</p>
          <p></p>
         </div>`
```

Requirement : In the second p tag I want to append the value of variable x . How do I do that ? Need help with the syntax.

Thanks!!

Comment: [Duplicate](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+js+put+variable+in+string) of [How to interpolate variables in strings in JavaScript, without concatenation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3304014/4642212).

Comment: See the [Template literal guide on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Strings#Template_literals).

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = 25;
document.getElementById("items").innerHTML += 
        `<div class="details">
          <p>Name</p>
          <p>${x}</p>
         </div>`
```

Try this out!