# Why isn't console.log in my nodeJS giving proper result?

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, console.log, yargs

When I am using

```
console.log("driving ${params.car} at the speed of ${params.speed}");
```

It is giving me result in terminal as

```
driving ${params.car} at the speed of ${params.speed}
```

Why isn't it printing the values?

Comment: Use ( " ) instead ( ` ) - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304014/how-to-interpolate-variables-in-strings-in-javascript-without-concatenation

Comment: Thank you. You saved me! I used it and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Just use (`) instead of (') or (").

Note that it is a backtick, not a quote.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use backquotes around the string in order for string interpolation to work.

```
console.log(`driving ${params.car} at the speed of ${params.speed}`);
```