# concatenate a variable to a html string in javaScript

Tags: javascript, html, function, concatenation, parameter-passing

Please be gentle with me, it is my first time uploading a question to stack overflow, and since I am rather new in programming I might be a bit vague in the terms.

My problem is that I have a function that places some markers on a map, this happens automatically when I load the site, these markers are different and contain different "trophies", that I have placed in a pop-up locked to the marker. However I want the program to be able to collect the trophies, therefore  I would like to call a function with the specific trophy as my parameter in my javaScript file when I click a button in my pop up. HTML.

So far it looks like this:

```js
function createMarker(coords, trophy) {
  var id
  // check if array is empty and set id to 0 if it is
  if (markers.length < 1) id = 0
  // else make id based on array length
  else id = markers[markers.length - 1]._id + 1
  // custom popup content with HTML that can be styled
  var popupContent =
    '<div id= "divTrophy">'+
    '<img src=' + trophy +'></img>' +
    '<button onClick="trophyCollection('+trophy+')">Collect trophy</button>'+
    '<button onclick="closePopUp()">Close pop up</button>'+
    '</div>'
```

```js
'<button onClick="trophyCollection('+trophy+')">Collect trophy</button>'+
```

The problem is in this line where I am for some reason not allowed to concat this way, which confuses me because it works fine in the line above in the `<img>`.

I really hope someone can help me, create my little treasure hunt around DK.

Comment: if trophy is a string, it still needs to be wrapped in quotes to be passed as a param `onClick="trophyCollection(\''+trophy+'\')"`

Comment: Hi. The problem is that string is not concatednated or it is that the click event is not raised?

Comment: Thank you Lawrence! It works :-D

Answer (score 1):

Try using string interpolation. Something like this.

```
`your_html_string ${your_dynamic_value} your_html_string`
```

You can find more info on interpolation here.
[How to interpolate variables in strings in JavaScript, without concatenation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304014/how-to-interpolate-variables-in-strings-in-javascript-without-concatenation)

Comment: If you're just going to link to other questions, you should flag it as a duplicate, not post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can insert your entire HTML inside of a backtick string and interpolate values like this:

```
let popupContent =
  `<div id= "divTrophy">
    <img src=${trophy}></img>
    <button onClick="trophyCollection(${trophy})">Collect trophy</button>
    <button onclick="closePopUp()">Close pop up</button>
  </div>`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try escaping them it should work, example

```
'<button onClick="trophyCollection(\''+trophy+'\')">Collect trophy</button>'+
```

Answer (score -1):

As suggested you can try [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```js
var popupContent = `<div id="divTrophy">
   <img src="${trophy}"/>
   <button onClick="trophyCollection('${trophy}')">Collect trophy</button>
   <button onclick="closePopUp()">Close pop up</button>
</div>`
```

Do note that as `trophy` is a string you still need to wrap it in quotes.