# .style.backgroundImage="url('my_image.png') does not work when image file name served as variable

Tags: javascript

Here is a function  which works perfectly when I serve the background file name as bracketed string.(ie "my _image.png")

```
function  mychoice_photo_show() {
  document.getElementById('mychoice_photo').style.backgroundImage="url('my _image.png')"
}
```

HERE IS THE PROBLEM:-

```
function mychoice_photo_show(img) {
  document.getElementById('mychoice_photo').style.backgroundImage="url(img)"
};
```

When I call it like so : `mychoice_photo_show("my_image.png")`

It does not call the requested image.

Should I look for any syntax like missing single quotes, or double quotes somewhere, or it just not supposed to work like that ?

Comment: One way is to concatenate the variable into the string you have like: `.style.backgroundImage="url(" + img + ")"`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to interpolate variables in strings in JavaScript, without concatenation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304014/how-to-interpolate-variables-in-strings-in-javascript-without-concatenation)

Comment: THANK YOU!. 
concatenating the phrase did the job!

i have just tried that  and succeeded after 4 hours of messing arround .

Answer (score 1):

Try like this.

```
function mychoice_photo_show(img) {
  document.getElementById('mychoice_photo').style.backgroundImage="url('" + img + "')"
};
```

Or ES6

```
function mychoice_photo_show(img) {
      document.getElementById('mychoice_photo').style.backgroundImage=`url('${img}')`
    };
```

For example

```js
function mychoice_photo_show(img) {
  document.getElementById('mychoice_photo').style.backgroundImage="url('" + img + "')"
};
```

```css
#mychoice_photo{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="mychoice_photo"></div>
<button onclick="mychoice_photo_show('https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_nature_wide.jpg')">Show image</button>
```

```js
function mychoice_photo_show(img) {
  document.getElementById('mychoice_photo').style.backgroundImage=`url('${img}')`
};
```

```css
#mychoice_photo{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="mychoice_photo"></div>
<button onclick="mychoice_photo_show('https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_nature_wide.jpg')">Show image</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would create a utility function that takes an element and image URL and set the `background-image` by using a [**template literal**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). I would then create a convenience call that finds your element and just passes that information down to the utility function.

**Note:** I converted the name of your function to lowerCamelCase instead of lower_snake_case because JavaScript recommended this.

```js
function showPhoto(element, imageUrl) {
  element.style.backgroundImage = `url("${imageUrl}")`;
}

function mychoicePhotoShow(imageUrl) {
  showPhoto(document.getElementById('mychoice_photo'), imageUrl);
}
```

Template literals have been [available](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#browser_compatibility) for quite some time now:

| Browser | Minimum Version |
| --- | --- |
| Chrome | 41 |
| Edge | 12 |
| Firefox | 34 |
| Safari | 9 |

Answer (score 1):

try this if es6 is available:

```js
function mychoice_photo_show(img) {
  document.getElementById('mychoice_photo').style.backgroundImage=`url('${img}')`
};
```

or this if es6 is not available:

```js
function mychoice_photo_show(img) {
  document.getElementById('mychoice_photo').style.backgroundImage="url('" + img + "')"
};
```