# How to put Dynamic id in checkbox in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, checkbox

I am attaching my html code to a variable(ctableData) which I am again appending to the main container.
Now I want to have dynamic id for the checkbox, So I am running a loop and incrementing the value of k in every iteration and then assigning the k as checkbox id. But this doesnt seem to be working?

```html
for(let k =1; k< x.length; k++){
ctableData += '<div class="table_container"><table id="table1" class="checkboxdiv"><tbody><tr><th>'+plan[0].medicalPlans[i].brokerName+' <input type="checkbox" id= k name="table1" value="table1" onchange="myFunction(event)"> </th></tr>
}
```

Comment: Use a template string.

Comment: Try like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/w6sbha4L/). Also , read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304014/how-to-interpolate-variables-in-strings-in-javascript-without-concatenation) post .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Use a [template string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) using backticks.

```
for(let k =1; k< x.length; k++){
ctableData += `<div class="table_container">
    <table id="table1" class="checkboxdiv">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th>'+plan[0].medicalPlans[i].brokerName+' 
            <input type="checkbox" id=${k} name="table1" value="table1" onchange="myFunction(event)" /> 
          </th>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>`
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your code is that you haven't used the value of k. You put k inside the string which does not evaluate to a loop variable. Use it just like you did for `plan[0].medicalPlans[i].brokerName` :

```
 for (let k = 1; k < x.length; k++) {
  ctableData += '<div class="table_container">
                   <table id="table1" class="checkboxdiv"><tbody><tr><th>' 
                  + plan[0].medicalPlans[i].brokerName + ' 
                    <input type="checkbox" id=' + k + ' name="table1" 
                   value="table1" onchange="myFunction(event)"> </th></tr>
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using template literals.

```
for(let k =1; k< x.length; k++){
ctableData += 
`<div class="table_container">
     <table id="table1" class="checkboxdiv">
         <tbody>
             <tr>
                 <th>'+plan[0].medicalPlans[i].brokerName+'
                    <input type="checkbox" id=${k} name="table1" value="table1" 
                    onchange="myFunction(event)"> 
                 </th>
             </tr>
         <tbody>
     <table>
</div>`
}
```